# Laravel query works with database.php strict=>false. How to make it work with strict=>true?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

There is a query that works when `strict => false` in `database.php` of Laravel. I don't want to make `strict => false`, I want it to remain `true`.

Is there a way to change this query and achieve the same results?

```
Transaction::where('contact_id', 9)
    ->with('allocations')
    ->whereHas("allocations", function ($query) {
        $query->havingRaw('transactions.credit > sum(amount)');
        $query->groupBy('transaction_id');
    })
    ->orDoesntHave("allocations")
    ->get();
```

Error when enabling strict mode

> Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list
> is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
> 'transaction_allocations.id' which is not functionally dependent on
> columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
> sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `transactions` where
> `contact_id` = 9 and exists (select * from `transaction_allocations`
> where `transactions`.`id` = `transaction_allocations`.`transaction_id`
> and `transaction_allocations`.`deleted_at` is null group by
> `transaction_id` having transactions.credit > sum(amount)) or not
> exists (select * from `transaction_allocations` where
> `transactions`.`id` = `transaction_allocations`.`transaction_id` and
> `transaction_allocations`.`deleted_at` is null))

Context:
There are two tables **transactions** and **transaction_allocations**.  One Transaction can have many allocations.

I am trying to find transactions that are not allocated fully.

Meaning: get transactions where **transaction.credit** field is greater than sum of amounts for that transaction in related table(transaction_allocations).

**Transaction Model**

```
Schema::create('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreignId('contact_id')->constrained();
    $table->decimal('credit', 19, 4)->nullable();
});
```

**Allocation Model**

```
Schema::create('transaction_allocations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->timestamp('created_at');
    $table->foreignId('transaction_id')->nullable()->constrained();
    $table->foreignId('bill_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('bills');
    $table->decimal('amount', 19, 4)->nullable();
});
```

**Relationship in Transaction Model**

```
public function allocations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TransactionAllocation::class);
}
```

Comment: Which error is shown when you enable strict mode?

Comment: Error added to question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` statements in strict mode require that all the non-aggregate fields (`COUNT`, `SUM`, `MAX`, etc.) in the `SELECT` statement be present in the `GROUP BY`.

As shown in the error, the `whereHas()` method has produced a `select *` query, however, your `GROUP BY` statement only has `transaction_id`.

To fix this, you can simply add `select('transaction_id')` to your `whereHas` call:

```
->whereHas("allocations", function ($query) {
    $query->select('transaction_id')
        ->havingRaw('transactions.credit > sum(amount)')
        ->groupBy('transaction_id');
})
```